# Automatically adding new Git branches to Trac

Tags: git, trac

How can I tell Trac about newly-added Git branches? Since talk about Git can get confusing quickly, here's a concrete example: Suppose I have a "central" Git server, foo.example.com, which my Trac installation exports, and on some host I:

```
$ git clone git@foo.example.com:/path/to/repo.git
$ cd repo
$ git checkout -b test_branch
$ git push -u origin test_branch
```

I now have a new branch on the central server called "test_branch", yet this is not accessible from Trac. How can I 1) make it accessible (e.g. under the "Visit" drop-down box) and 2) make this happen automatically for any new branch?

Update: Maybe I should mention that the repository exported by Trac is not "the" central repo. It's owned by another user and currently the webserver user doesn't have access. Instead there's a separate repo owned by and exported by the web server user. Both the central repo and the web server happen to be on the same machine, though.

STNBU

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read about [Trac repository administration](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin) in the authoritative wiki documentation.

There is certainly no such thing like auto-discovery for repositories in a give path. You could use trac-admin calls from a terminal to add new repositories, if you dislike doing it via admin web-UI. And make sure to [get repository synchronization right](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracRepositoryAdmin#ExplicitSync) for every repository as well.

If this is a repeating task, you may want to write a simple Python script to do it all more efficiently.

Comment: I should have remarked long ago: Since this is the server on which the "central" repo is posted, I just gave Trac read access to the actual repo-in-question and it all just works. No need for any commit hooks. All the branches are there, etc. Pretty obvious in retrospect.

Your response was on the mark, though.